# How to verify new accounts

Tags: php, html, email, mysqli, html-email

So I'm kinda a noob when it comes to signup/login as well as emails.  My problem is that I want to make a verification email.  I already have a functioning email that will send to you when you hit the Sign Up button (If you want to check out that it's rediku.com).  The issue is when the email was originally made it had a form with a hidden field that had a generated token that could be used to identify the user and verify them. Unfortunately email clients will block emails with forms in them.  So I had to resort to using an anchor link.

Basically, my question is... How could I verify a specific persons account by sending them an email with a link?

Comment: Check some of the activation you've gotten yourself for hints. Just send a link with a param `yoursite.com/verify.php?token=sometokenhere`, on that page you verify the token (if it isn't expired).

Comment: What aspect here is it that you have a problem with? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried using hidden form tags with my token but unfortunately email clients block that... I don't know where to even start with something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are having a registration form on your website.
I assume you are sending the data to a file named performRegistration.php.

inside performRegistration.php:

```
// TBD sanitizing input data
$newUser = new User(); // I am assuming you build a class for your users
$newUser->setVerified(false);
// TBD save form data to user object
// generate a custom key for new user
$newUser->setRegisterKey = MD5('someSaltString'.date('u')); // very basic!
$newUser->save(); // validate data (like user already registered, and stuff like that) and save to db
$newUser->sendRegistrationMail(); // I like libs like swiftmailer
```

As @JimL pointed out, you should use a basic link with a token.
I would do something like: `yoursite.com/verify.php?verify[username]=aUsername&verify[token]=theMd5TokenGenerated`
That way you can lookup for the username inside your db and check the corresponding key generated. You have to make sure two users do not get the same registration key if you want to look up the dataset during verification process if you do not add the (unique) username to the link.

Inside verify.php:

```
// TBD catch $_GET and sanitize data
$getVars = $_GET['verify'];
if(array_key_exists('token', $getVars)){
    if(!empty($_GET['token']) && !empty($_GET['username'])) {
       // TBD get user from db where username and key match the submitted values from the link
      // if you can find a matching dataset:
      $newUser->setVerified(true);
      // start a session, add a cookie, login user
      // do some great stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very basic though. Please consider using libraries and frameworks taking care about stuff like that for you. There is a lot of security stuff to consider...

Comment: When I try to get the GET token variable from the url and I run the `if(empty($_GET['token'])) {}` it comes as empty.

Comment: What does the link look like?

Comment: try ```var_dump($_REQUEST);```

Comment: I edited the answer to go more in detail with the verification data fetching. (changed the link too!)